# Magento 2 cms_index_noroute.xml not having any affect

Tags: magento2, layout

I'm trying to gut the cms block from the 404 page. Which i successfully did for the homepage, by using the following home layout file.

```
 <referenceBlock name="cms_page" remove="true" />
```

However it doesnt matter what i do to cms_index_noroute.xml even if i change the core version it just does not seem to be using this file at all. Also when i switch of template hints and blocks this does not seem to actually be adding anything.

I'm ultimately trying to change this cms block into a template file block but for whatever reason it does not seem to be using this layout file. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out the file is named incorrectly in the core, the correct file name should be cms_noroute_index.xml

Answer (score 0):

Not only this name (cms_index_noroute.xml) is incorrect. Same thing in handle declaration in vendor\magento\module-cms\etc\frontend\page_types.xml. With this the widget module is not working correctly, too. Widgets placed on "CMS No-Route Default Page" or "CMS No-Route Page" are not shown in frontend. So we have to extend these handle declarations, too! For further explanations (currently only German), please see [here](https://www.econcess.de/blog/onlineshop-erstellung-magento/179-magento-2-widget-wird-auf-404-seite-no-route-nicht-angezeigt).